# TOR not letting me download attachments

Tags: error

TOR not letting me download any attachments from email accounts. All I get are the filename of something and file size of 0 bytes.

I tried another email provider and still cannot download any attachments.

Seems a snafu?

Comment: This is likely specific to the email provider, Tor Browser lets me download email attachments fine. If you can provide us a set of steps to reproduce the issue ourselves then we can investigate further.